# それだけ　in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, translation

This is from a Manga, and I don't quite understand how the soredake in the 2nd bubble fits into it? But maybe I am completely off with the meaning of the sentences as a whole - so I've put what I think they mean in italics as well.

Bubble 1:

俺はどっちかって

いうと

そういうのは

鈍い方だけど

*I'd say I am a reserved (quiet/solemn) person, but*

Bubble 2:

それだけ　俺も

航を見てたって

ことだ

*I also watched Kou*

Does the soredake simply add an "only"? i.e. I also only watched Kou.

Any pointers are much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 「それだけ + Phrase or Mini-Sentence + って/という + こと（だ/です）」

would need to be remembered as a set phrase because it is a very common one.  I means:

> "That is/proves (just) how much ~~~~."

Thus, the sentence in question means:

"***That is (just) how closely I was watching Kou.***"

Though there is not enough context provided, I would highly doubt that 「鈍{にぶ}い」 means "reserved, quiet, or solemn" here as you stated.  I would think it is more like "slow" or "dull-witted".

Finally, regarding your translation of 「も」....

I will not go into details as it is not part of your question, but you will need to learn not to use "***too***" or "***also***" in your translation every time you see 「も」 because that is not what it always means.  「も」 is an extremely nuanced particle.

Comment: Thank you! That was really quick. I thought that the 'soredake' might be interacting with other parts of that sentence but couldn't come up with anything. [And yes, I am aware that 'mo' can have different usages, I was just hung up on the 'soredake'. Thank you for pointing it out, though. :)]

Answer (score 1):

Bubble 1: The speeker confessed that he (or she) is not so sensitive to something (I guess other's emotion).

(I'm not sure what is the main subject in the cartoon, but I gess this even insencitive person might has noticed something that is the main subject related "航(a boy?)". This cartoon is a love story?)

Then,

Bubble 2:
I guess, the meaning "それだけ" is the following,

Even insencitive person like me have noticed the internal something of "航," because I watched him (or her) more carfully than usual.

（何かに気が付くだけ（それだけ）、俺も航を見ていた）

Comment: Thank you, makes sense. It is  a love story. A love triangle to be precise. :)